# Find and remove matches from two lists in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I've got two int lists xs and ys (of arbitrary length) and want to remove the duplicates that appear in each list efficiently. Since you can't/shouldn't edit a list as you loop through it, my attempt was:

```
matches = [match for match in xs if match in ys]
for match in matches: 
    xs.remove(match)
    ys.remove(match)
```

But importantly if the value comes up twice in xs but once in ys, this yields an error, since the "if match in ys" evaluates to true twice for the same value, but I need it to only count once.

So to clarify, if:

```
xs = [0, 2, 4, 8, 8, 100]
ys = [1, 3, 5, 8, 8, 8, 10]
```

then 8 needs to be removed twice from both lists.

How can I do this efficiently? Thanks

edit: Lists not necessarily ordered and in practice both lists are likely to contain duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use multisets (`collections.Counter`) for the intersection. If you expect a large number of duplicates and your lists are large, then it is advisable to avoid `.remove` since it is expensive. A list comprehension scales much better. We use some modest itertools trickery to filter out the marked duplicates. Please note that this could be adapted, for example to not remove the first but instead the last occurrences etc.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat, chain

xc = Counter(xs)
yc = Counter(ys)
matches = xc & yc
tr = repeat(True)
rm = {k: chain(repeat(False, m), tr) for k, m in matches.items()}
xs = [x for x in xs if not x in rm or next(rm[x])]
rm = {k: chain(repeat(False, m), tr) for k, m in matches.items()}
ys = [y for y in ys if not y in rm or next(rm[y])]
```

Note that this only works if your elements are hashable.

Comment: It works for only 2 duplicates, but for not for n duplicates, have updated the example to show this

Comment: @BenJones Ah, I see. Could you clarify? What should happen in this situation: `xs=[1,1,1,1,2]` `ys=[1,1,3]`? Desired output? `xs=[1,1,1,2]` `ys=[1,3`]? or `xs=[1,1,2]` `ys=[3]` or `xs=[1,2]` `ys=[3]`?

Comment: There are two 1's that are common to both lists, so the desired output is xs = [1,1,2] and ys = [3], sorry for confusion!

Comment: @BenJones: Sorted. Could you verify please?

Comment: It does seem to work, though I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: The newest edit yields a type error: 
 matches = xs in ys
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Counter'

Comment: @BenJones Sorry, I'm new to those `Counter` objects myself. They implement somthing like a multiset, like a set but with multiplicity. For example intersecting them gives for each element  the smaller number of occurrences in the two. And it has this `elements()` iterator which is useful for the removal loop because it yields each element as often as it is in the multiset. I think it should work fine now.

Comment: It looks good thanks, appears to work well. Any idea of the efficiency?

Comment: I believe removing elements from lists is not very efficient. If you do not care about the order of elements it is almost certainly more efficient to subtract the intersection `matches` from each multiset `xc`, `yc`.

Comment: @BenJones I've got rid of the `remove` bits and depending on the number of duplicates it is much (x100+) faster for large (100,000 elements) lists now.